# How to put a gallery into a widget in the home screen?

Tags: android, layout, android-appwidget

I am trying to create a gallery inside a widget in the home screen ....as i am new to android please do give me guidelines and the source code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Here is the [list of views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) that you can put in an appwidget layout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I came to know that image view  can be put into the appwidget layout from the android developers site . If so , can anyone give suggestions on how to put an image view into the appwidget layout....